# SSIS packages gets run when asp.net page is refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net web page with a button that when clicked it calls 2 stored procedures, then runs an SSIS package as a SQL Agent Job and finally reloads the data on the page. This all runs fine.

My problem is if the page is then refreshed using the browser refresh button it executes the button click event again.

How can I stop this from happening?

Thanks
Noelle

Comment: This is a default behavior of almost all browsers. Not only `Refresh` button, but the `Backward` & `Forward` button would have the same effect.

Comment: You can have a token placed in session and mark that token as processed in the first click. Check if the token has already been processed then ignore the button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two separate pages

1. Which has the button, which when clicked calls your SPs and runs the SSIS package as a SQL Agent Job
2. Which loads data

Then

- Redirect to page 2 from your page 1 button click after the SQL Server Agent Job is finished.
- Load required data in the page load event of page 2

Have a property wrapped on `ViewState` in page 1 like this.

```
protected Boolean IsRequestAlreadyProcessed
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(this.ViewState["IsRequestAlreadyProcessed"]);
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["IsRequestAlreadyProcessed"] = value;
    }
}
```

Now check this property in your page 1 button click event like this.

```
protected void yourButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsRequestAlreadyProcessed)
    {
        this.IsRequestAlreadyProcessed = true;
        //Carry out all your SQL Agent Job operations here...
        Response.Redirect("~/ToYourPage2.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Though this is not full proof, it certainly is a workaround the problem.